# i have written code to create issue in JIRA with java code by usign JSON but its not working can anybody please look into it?

Tags: java, jira

I tried with below code to create issue i am not getting any error after executing it but it doesn't create any issue in **JIRA** :

```
package DEMO1_JIRA_API;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.json.*;

public class JIRA {
    static String URL = "JIRA_URL";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL jiraREST_URL = new URL(URL);
            URLConnection urlConnection = jiraREST_URL.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) jiraREST_URL
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(getJSON_Body(), "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(getJSON_Body() + "/" + encodedData);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                    "Basic " + Base64.encode("uname:pwd".getBytes(), 0));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(encodedData.length()));
            conn.connect();
            conn.getOutputStream().write(encodedData.getBytes());

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("inp - " + inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getJSON_Body() {
        JsonObject createIssue = Json
                .createObjectBuilder()
                .add("fields",
                        Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("project",
                                        Json.createObjectBuilder().add("key",
                                                "Automation Framework"))
                                .add("summary", "test summary")
                                .add("description", "test desc")
                                .add("issuetype",
                                        Json.createObjectBuilder().add("id",
                                                "10106"))
                                .add("assignee",
                                        Json.createObjectBuilder().add("id",
                                                "ABC"))).build();

        return createIssue.toString();
    }
}
```

This code is not giving any error in eclipse but its not creating any issue in JIRA.

Can someone please look into it and provide any working example like how to fetch specific issue from JIRA and how to create it.

Comment: Edit your title. Indent and format your code.

Comment: Done. updated title + formatted my code with indentation...
can somebody please look into it...

Comment: First, build a JSON object the way you expect to see it after the objectbuilder is done (either build it manually, or capture the output after a run). Post the sanitized result in your question, so the community can confirm that the JSON itself looks good. Second, verify that your API calls are working with the above JSON. Use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or something similar to manually make the API call and verify that it did (or did not) work.